# Best solution after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I have a form which generates a email using Google Apps Mail, and all I want really its to do is to not go to the different page after pressing Submit, although I want it to still generate the email.

Any ideas what is the best way to do it? I learn jQuery now, so solutions in it are more than welcome.

```
<form class="flex-form" id="gform" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/..../exec" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
  <input id="formName" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" value="" required autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  <input id="formNumber" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="(0034) 606248059" name="phone-number" required autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  <input id="formGeo" type="text" placeholder="Tap to share location" name="coordinates" required autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Us Request">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the form's "submit" event with Javascript.

```
$('gform').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( ! confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?'))
        return false;

    // ....
});
```

That will catch the "submit" event and prevent the event's default action, which would be to POST the form to the URL given in the `action` attribute. Remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the form, better handle it all in one place.

Next, you need to send the data yourself. Easiest way is to use either jQuery's `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` functions, together with `$('gform').serialize()` to transform the form's data fields into a string, ready to be POSTed.